# Android - Full Screen without moving the content

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-statusbar, android-fullscreen, android-window

I am developing a reading app from where users can read multiple types of documents.

This app also has a feature to enable full screen by touching any part of the screen. I am able to enable/disable full screen by hiding the status bar and the tool bar (`ActionBar`) with the following line of codes:

```
if (toolbar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    appbar.animate().translationY(-112).setDuration(600L)
            .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }).start();
} else {
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    appbar.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(600L).start();
}
```

But the real issue is when I enable full screen the content moves upwards and when disable it moves downwards.

I don't want to move my content. I have seen in Google doc app that content does not move while enabling/disabling full screen.

Using `RelativeLayout` instead of `CoordinatorLayout` as a root layout I can avoid toolbar pushes the content but it pushes a little bit when I hide the status bar.

Please help.

Comment: moves upwards/downwards because the ActionBar pushes it up and down?

Comment: @Zain yes but how can we avoid this? In Google doc app the content does not move.

Comment: Do you use the default ActionBar or a customized one in layout?

Comment: Using `RelativeLayout` instead of `CoordinatorLayout` as a root layout I can avoid toolbar pushes the content but it pushes a little bit when I hide the status bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Using `RelativeLayout` instead of `CoordinatorLayout` as a root layout I can avoid toolbar pushes the content but it pushes a little bit when I hide the status bar.

Now your issue is that the status bar pushes the activity content down when it's shown.

So, to solve this you can make the status bar overlapping with the activity window by adding the below to the activity's `onCreate()` method

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, 
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
}
```

**UPDATE**

> what to use if build SDK is lower than kitkat?

To support APIs below Kitkat try to create a style.xml file for (v-19) qualifier, and add the below attributes

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item> 
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

**UPDATE:** using custom ActionBar

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:text="@string/long_text"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        </ScrollView>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:background="#9E0557B5"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Behavior

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        }
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        TextView content = findViewById(R.id.content);
        content.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (getSupportActionBar().isShowing()) {
                    getSupportActionBar().hide();
                    showSystemBar(false);
                }
                else {
                    getSupportActionBar().show();
                    showSystemBar(true);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void showSystemBar(boolean isDisplayed) {

        int uiOptions;
        if (isDisplayed) {
            // show status bar
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE;
                getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
            }
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        } else {
            // hide status bar
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
                getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
            } else {
                getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            }
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        }

    }

}
```

Use `NoActionBar` theme int style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Override style.xml (v.19)

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>
```

Preview

[image]

Comment: what to use if build SDK is lower than kitkat?

Comment: @FaisalShaikh I just updated the answer, hope it works

Comment: @FaisalShaikh welcome brother .. if you would like to use the `CoordinatorLayout` instead, try to use `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` at the root layout of your activity (try to use both true/false)

Comment: I already tried `fitsSystemWindows` but it does not work. Let me know if you have any sample github project for the same.

Comment: @FaisalShaikh I tackled this by creating a custom `ActionBar` wrapped in `AppBarLayout`, and made it overlapping with the activity content within the xml layout itself using the constraints, no special attributes I used. Of course `setSupportActionBar(myToolbar)` in java ..

Comment: I tried to do it but could not. Would you mind to share layout file. You can update the answer so this will be helpful for other users too.

Comment: Do you mean the custom action bar?

Comment: Yes. Custom action bar.

Comment: I tried the same layout, style and java file. everything is working fine but status bar collapse on toolbar. is there anything missing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217675/discussion-between-zain-and-faisal-shaikh).